# Inherited 'send as' permissions for mailbox on Exchange 2010, from where?

Tags: permissions, exchange

I have a pair of users who are able to send as for a particular mailbox on Exchange Server 2010. Both users have full access permission to that mailbox but NOT send as permissions. 
I have been scouring AD everywhere as to why they are able to send as for this particular mailbox in mention but no joy.

In ADUC, the mailbox doesn't have any of the users listed there for send as. Where else can I look or what Powershell script can I run to find this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell/Exchange Management Shell command you seek is [Get-MailboxPermission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998218%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

---

> This example returns permissions on the mailbox by its SMTP address john@contoso.com.
>
> Get-MailboxPermission -Identity john@contoso.com | Format-List

---

Comment: Noob, Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I ended up using this instead for more granular results: Get-Mailbox |Get-ADPermission | where{($_.ExtendedRights –like “*Send-As*”) –and($_.IsInherited –eq$false) –and –not($_.User –like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”)} |FT -Wrap